# Is there a function that does the opposite of get_object_or_404()

Tags: django

Is there a function like the get_object_or_404 to not display a 404 error? I have this in my views and I would like to display the page regardless if it finds posts:

```
tag = get_object_or_404(Keyword, slug=tag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think django doesn't have it is because django shouldn't assume what's the default value if the query is not found. Do this:

```
try:
    tag = Keyword.objects.get(slug=tag)
except Keyword.DoesNotExist:
    tag = None
```